# Desired Revert if Condition Is True

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

What is the best way to revert inside a function if a particular condition is true? Sometimes safeguarding with require statements is not enough, i.e.

```
    uint256 constant public OFFER_LIMIT = 500 ether;


         function buyTheObjective(address _customer, uint256 _offer) internal returns (uint256) {
                require(limitRemovalDate > 0, "[!] Sale has expired" );

                // some code here which is only dependent of the require statement.
                //  
                //
                if (now < limitRemovalDate && _offer > OFFER_LIMIT) {

                    // What is the best way to revert here?
                    // I want to reject people from overspending 
                    // until a certain elapse of time.
                }
```

Comment: How about...... `revert("some message")`???

Comment: P.S.: You my as well remove that entire `if` statement, and do `require(now < limitRemovalDate && _offer > OFFER_LIMIT, "your message");`, but that's technically the same as `if` + `revert`, just a little cleaner.

Comment: but what if there's some code which is dependent of the first require and not the if statement? I've edited the question for clarity.

Comment: Edited what answer? Why would you edit an answer to begin with???

Comment: Well, make up your mind, do you want to revert, or do you want some code to be executed (and transaction runs to completion)?

Comment: I want both. I want the revert checking to happen early and to only be operational until a certain time has elapsed, once the time has elapsed then the reverting condition should be ignored in future function executions.

Comment: Still not clear what it is that you want. 1. There is a `require` statement in your code - do you want it to run always? 2. There is then an `if` statement - what do you want inside it? What do you want before it? What do you want after? What are the circumstances under which you want to revert? Remember, reverting in our context (the Ethereum blockchain in general and Solidity in specific) means that **ALL** state-changes that took place during the transaction are reverted. So if reverting (under this definition) is not what you mean, then please restate your intentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
if (now < limitRemovalDate && _offer > OFFER_LIMIT)
    revert("some message");
```

Or you could do this:

```
require(now < limitRemovalDate && _offer > OFFER_LIMIT, "some message");
```

Which is technically the same just cleaner.